# How do you get mylyn to open and close projects?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I like mylyn task management, and the way contexts only show me what I'm working on.

Is there a way to take this one step further, and have a task switch close any project that isn't part of the context?

I'm using 3.5.0.I20110301-2328 with Eclipse 3.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**context**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Context_2) in Mylyn does mentions:

> **Manage open editors to match task context** -
>   When checked, activating a task will automatically open editors corresponding to the most interesting files in the task context.
>   **When deactivating a task, all editors will automatically close**.
>   While a task is active, files that become less interesting will automatically close as you work.

But that don't include projects, and <del>I didn't see any bug report asking for that feature</del>: as the [OP James Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73046/james-moore) reports in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175711/how-do-you-get-mylyn-to-open-and-close-projects/5202164#5202164), the [**bug 170232**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=170232) tracks that issue.
I presume the cost of switching context would be too high if it involved closing/opening projects (instead of just closing/opening Editors), and reading from the bug 170232, it seems to be the case.

> Personally, I don't think that it is necessary to close projects when closing
>   tasks.
>   The important part is to open projects if necessary when opening tasks. If you do that, then the performance should not be an issue when you switch tasks.
>   Closing projects on task close, should be optional: e.g. pop-up a dialog asking the user whether to close or not.
>
> Think about it this way: if you expect your users to always make sure the project is open before activating a task, then there should be no performance impact for doing that for them.

Comment: It's a cost I'm going to pay anyway - it's just a question of whether or not I have to do it myself, or have Mylyn do it for me.

Comment: @James: so the answer would be in this case: you might have to do it yourself, because I don't see Mylyn closing projects when switching task.

Answer (score 1):

Mylyn doesn't do this.  The first request for this was back in 2007, and it's still open, with some activity about a year ago:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=170232

Comment: good catch (+1). I have included a summary of the conclusions of that bug in my answer.